# Display top values and the sum of all other values in R

Tags: r, sqldf

After I use `order by TOTAL desc` in sqldf, my results are

```
NAME  TOTAL
 A     100
 E     85
 D     75
 C     55
 B     30
 F     25
 G     20
 I     15
 H     10
```

I want to display the top 5 (in this case) and the rest to be summed as 'Others': 
Like this:

```
NAME   TOTAL
A       100
E       85
D       75
C       55
B       30
Others  70
```

Is there a way I can do it using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is already sorted, one way would be as follows. It is quite verbose, so I am curious to see other solution approaches.

```
df = read.table(text='NAME  TOTAL
A     100
E     85
D     75
C     55
B     30
F     25
G     20
I     15
H     10',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(NAME=ifelse(NAME %in% head(NAME,5),NAME,'other')) %>% 
  mutate(NAME=factor(NAME,levels=unique(NAME))) %>%
  group_by(NAME) %>% 
  summarize(TOTAL=sum(TOTAL))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  NAME   TOTAL
  <fctr> <int>
1 A        100
2 E         85
3 D         75
4 C         55
5 B         30
6 other     70
```

Hope this helps!